# Database queries issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

```
use AdventureWorks2017
Go 
--select FirstName,DueDate  ,
--Product.Name,ProductInventory.ProductID,LastName
--from  Person.Person , enter code here
--Production.Product,
--Production.ProductInventory,
--Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
--where person.BusinessEntityID = Production.Product.ProductID and  > > > > > 
person.BusinessEntityID=PurchaseOrderID 
--and Person.LastName like  'a%awa' and( ProductInventory.ProductID between 882 and 992);
**strong text**
select NationalIDNumber,Person.FirstName,JobTitle
from HumanResources.Employee ,Person.Person inner join
     Person.Person 
     using (Person.Person.PK_Person_BusinessEntityID)
where JobTitle like 'Eng%';
```

Error message:

> Msg 321, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
> "Person" is not a recognized table hints option.

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479936/sql-join-using-using-column-name-is-not-a-recognized-table-hints-option

Comment: `using (Person.Person.PK_Person_BusinessEntityID)` ... is that meant to be an index hint? Or a join condition? Because currently it's neither.

Answer (score 1):

you can't `using()` as join parameter in sql server, you have to use `on` 
also you are joiing to person table twice ,and never use explicit join:

```
select NationalIDNumber,Person.FirstName,JobTitle
from HumanResources.Employee e
inner join Person.Person p 
 on p.PK_Person_BusinessEntityID =  e.PK_Person_BusinessEntityID
where JobTitle like 'Eng%';
```